# nouveau failed to create 0x00 ... after install gtx 1080

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a system with 4 gtx 1080 cards, (with no integrated graphic chip)
I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS server on my system, but after installation, booting got stuck at "nouveau failed to create 0x00 ..., -22"
Is it a problem with nouveau that it cannot recognize such a newly released card?
Anybody have a solution? or suggestion for other OS (like CentOS)?

Answer (score 1):

The 'new' NVIDIA GTX 1000 graphics adapters have compatibilty issues with the nouveau drivers.
Add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` **at the end of the linux line** before booting the system.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key to add the parameter, then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
To make this solution permanent, add the parameter to GRUB configuration in /etc/default/grub.

Open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to this line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
that it reads : **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and confirm the change you've made by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>.
Then execute : `sudo update-grub` to update the GRUB configuration.